# Multi Threading with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I've written a hot folder utility which works great when one file at a time is dropped.  When a file is dropped into the hot folder, I add the filename to an array and then use a timer event to see if the array is empty and if it isn't, take the 1st value and start processing.

If I drop 2 files the first file is processed before the 2nd file is processed.  I've been researching Background workers and struggling to implement.  Any insight on how to get each timer event to trigger in a  new thread easily?

Comment: Wow, this is a broad topic.  You need to show what you've tried and ask a *specific* question.  Also, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why does the order in which the files are processed matter?  What defines "the order"?  If you drop them at the same time (in a single copy action) what inherently makes one file "first"?

Comment: Are you using FileSystemWatcher or is this a roll-your-own version?

Comment: Did you go over the msdn article? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywkkz4s1(v=vs.140).aspx Can you show what you have been doing?

Comment: The way you probably should do this is to create a class that contains a BGW, timer, code for processing the files, and property for the filename.  For each file, create an instance of the class, set the filename, and the class then creates the BGW and processes the file.

Comment: The order of the files being processed doesn't matter.  

I am using FileSystemWatcher using the OnCreated event

I have read the MSDN article but not must be slow after the holiday this weekend because its not making sense to me.

I'll reread the MSDN article after some coffee in a bit.

Comment: Put the FSW inside a collection class with a FileItem class.  When the FSW fires, add the item to the collection.  Add a timer (1) which goes off every 1.5-2.5 secs.  Process the files.  Garnish with events to report changes (queued, complete, error) to the form (?).  Each file may need a minimum delay or min 1 timer cycle before processing to be sure the OS is done creating.  No BGW really needed - the FSW runs on its own thread already.

Comment: Plutonix - Great insight, that is what I was hoping.  I enable my FSW with one button, initialize the path, buffer size, etc.  When an event (OnCreated) fires, I add the full path to an array and then I have a time that fires ever 2 seconds, takes the files from the array and process the file.  Can you provide some sample code on how to do what your explaining?  Thanks.

Comment: When more than one person comments, you need to use @username to be sure the person gets pinged.  Yes, but please fix your question -  it is very broad (and 1 vote from being closed); as is, the requirement for processing them in order seems specious.